# How can you get a list of all subscribed presence or public channels?

Tags: socket.io, laravel-echo, pusher-js

Is there a way of getting a list of all channels (or channel names) the current Echo instance is subscribed to?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

```
Echo.connector.channels
```